# How to increase a Corda node's memory limit within a Docker container

Tags: docker, corda

When deploying a Corda node the JVM `XmX` argument is used to increase the node's memory limit but when deploying via container the official Corda image throws a warning

> WARNING: the use of the -Xmx flag is not recommended within docker containers. Use the --memory option passed to the container to limit heap size

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.4/docker/src/bash/run-corda.sh#L4

Setting the memory limit for the container is insufficient since the node itself crashes with an OOM exception inside the container.

When using open source you can bypass the `XmX` parameter by setting node configuration as follows:

```
custom = {
   jvmArgs: [ "-Xmx1G", "-XX:+UseG1GC" ]
}
```

Is there a way to set the Corda node memory limit via dockerfile or docker compose rather than configuration?

Comment: How did you manage to use this custom option? I tried to use with Cordform in my build.grade but it doesn't work.

Comment: This was placed in a `node.conf` which was generated for the node and placed inside the container. I haven't used Cordform for docker deployment. You might try using docker compose directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use docker-compose to pass the `JVM_ARGS` as an environment variable to the container.

```
 partya:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.4
    container_name: partya
    ports:
      - "10006:10201"
    environment:   
      - JVM_ARGS=-Xmx6g -Xms2g -XX:+UseG1GC
    volumes:
      - ./Network/PartyA/node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./Network/PartyA/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./Network/PartyA/persistence:/opt/corda/persistence
      - ./Network/PartyA/logs:/opt/corda/logs
      - ./Network/Shared/cordapps:/opt/corda/cordapps
      - ./Network/Shared/node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
      - ./Network/Shared/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
```

But this won't help you to get rid of the Warning since the script would still be used to run the node.

If you really want to get rid of the warning you could use a `command` to override the default run script.

```
partya:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.4
    container_name: partya
    ports:
      - "10006:10201"
    command: java -Dcapsule.jvm.args=-Xmx6g -Xms2g -XX:+UseG1GC -jar /opt/corda/bin/corda.jar --base-directory /opt/corda --config-file /etc/corda/node.conf
    volumes:
      - ./Network/PartyA/node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./Network/PartyA/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./Network/PartyA/persistence:/opt/corda/persistence
      - ./Network/PartyA/logs:/opt/corda/logs
      - ./Network/Shared/cordapps:/opt/corda/cordapps
      - ./Network/Shared/node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
      - ./Network/Shared/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
```

Comment: It sounds like the warning can be safely ignored? I had assumed seeing the XmX argument would cause problems but if setting the JVM_ARGS as an environment is safe then I'll do that.

Comment: I think it's fine to use the -Xmx option to set the maximum heap size based on the container limits. I found a good explanation about this here: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/